Fast API endpoint handlers
I'm not so experienced at developing Fast API apps. As I program in different languages, I often get confused as how things are done in a python way.
I have this piece of code, and I would like to know if this is the correct way to handle endpoints in fastapi. I'm more used to program in an object-oriented way, but maybe for this kind of app, the approach is usually different.
@router.post(
    "/upload", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=list[Student]
)
async def upload_csv_file(
    file: UploadFile,
    hasher: Annotated[object, Depends(dependencies.get_hash)],
    db: Annotated[object, Depends(dependencies.get_db)],
):
    try:
        # Check if content-type is a text/csv
        if file.content_type != "text/csv":
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_415_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
                detail="CSV file must be provided",
            )
        repository = StudentRepository(db)
        service = StudentService(repository)
        content = await file.read()
        content = content.decode("utf-8")

        res = service.create_students_from_string(content, hasher)

        return res
    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e


import
There's some missing Review Context,
which obscures the meaning of the code you posted.
Please include import statements; they are an
essential part of your source code.
There's not even a GitHub link to help fill in the gaps.
annotations

correct way to handle endpoints

@router.post(
    "/upload", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, response_model=list[Student]
)

Yes, this looks about right.
Though I confess I don't recognize the Student annotation -- I would
have anticipated "... , response_model: list[Student]",
with : colon rather than an = assignment.
And maybe with the status code appearing last.
    hasher: Annotated[object, Depends(dependencies.get_hash)],
    db: Annotated[object, Depends(dependencies.get_db)],

Those certainly look like type annotations, but were they perhaps
originally written a few years ago, or intended to target an ancient interpreter?
I would expect Any rather than object,
and the Annotated seems on the redundant side.
from typing import Any
        content = await file.read()
        content = content.decode("utf-8")

type nit: We assign bytes to content, then assign a unicode str to it.
Consider inventing two distinct names for those,
or just combine it all into a single expression.
useless try / catch
    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e

I can't imagine why you went to the trouble of
opening a try block there.
Simply let the exception bubble up the call stack normally.
It will have the same effect.

Thanks @J_H for the observations. I appreciate all the comments.
